# Is it possible to stream music from Windows Media Player using "Connected Media" or otherwise?

Tags: mediaplayer, htc

One of the HTC "exclusive" apps is "Connected Media" which claims that it can play music from DLNA servers. It is my understanding that this is the protocol that Windows Media player uses to stream media, but whenever I search for servers, it seems unable to find any (even though there should be a choice of at least two PCs and even a Humax HDR). Is there "someothing special" that needs to be done to get it to work, or is the app just so buggy that it is unusable? Are there any built in/free alternatives?

Comment: I've just noticed that the image on the [DLNA website](http://www.dlna.org/) even depicts a Windows Phone, so perhaps a built in alternative would be more useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Windows phones have a manufacturer specific DLNA player:

- Nokia PlayTo
- LG SmartShare
- Samsung Allshare
- HTC Connected Media

In Windows Media Player you need to enable *Allow remote control of my Player* and *Automatically allow devices to play my media* under your libraries stream menu.

A nice guide can be found [here](http://wmpoweruser.com/how-to-configure-dlna-between-windows-phone-and-windows-7/).

The functionality is not limited to Windows Media Player or Windows and will work with any DLNA server.

Comment: As far as I can see, Nokia's PlayTo is exactly that - it'll let me play media from my phone to another device -- I want to be able to play media from another device to my phone

Comment: ...and on my HTC, the furthest I can get is "Unable to connect to media server Please try again." :(

Comment: @RowlandShaw and you verified your WMP sharing settings? If the settings on your PC and phone look good, then try turning off your firewall.

Comment: I'm able to stream media to other devices OK - I'm starting to think it's just a buggey offering from HTC, and that Nokia only does it the other way around :(