# How can I stream music stored on my computer to my phone?

Tags: zune, music, zune-player, 8.0, google

On my Android Phone, I use Google Play Music. I install an app on my computer that syncs my music with Google's cloud. On my phone, I can listen to this music whenever it is connected to the internet.

It would be nice to do something similar on Windows Phone. My music library is far too large to fit on my phone, so a streaming service is necessary.

Comment: See also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/779/106

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize **DLNA** to access media on other devices in your home network (this is how most devices pull this off). [This link](http://wmpoweruser.com/how-to-configure-dlna-between-windows-phone-and-windows-7/) will bring you to a detailed article on how to set it up.

If you have a Nokia device you have access to an app called "Play to", you will find in your "Nokia Collection" marketplace option.

htc has this option as well under their HTC marketplace option, the app is named "HTC Connected Media"

Now if you are looking to do this from the cloud, you can place the music in your SkyDrive and stream it anywhere.

Comment: "You can place the music in your SkyDrive and stream it anywhere" Great news! My Windows Phone (8X) hasn't arrived yet, so I haven't been able to play around with this.

Comment: I've had "issues" with the HTC "Connected Media" app in the past, but you may be more successful (it kept failing to retrieve the track listings) - the Nokia "Play To" app appears to only allow you to share media from the phone to other DLNA clients, and not the other way around.

Comment: Linada is also an app that let's you play music from a DLNA server. The only drawback for me is that user interface is a little bit confusing.

Comment: I finally got my phone, and SkyDrive doesn't really work for me. I can stream a single song at a time, but I can't use it as a general music player like I could with Google Play. I'm un-accepting this answer, since I'm looking for a cloud-based solution.