# How to stream music from phone to my Xbox 360?

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-920, xbox-music

I have an Xbox 360. When I use my Windows 8.1 laptop I'm able to go to Charms -> Devices -> Play to and then select my Xbox to send the music I'm listening on to the Xbox. There is no Charms on my Lumia 920 so how do I send the music from the Xbox Music app to my Xbox 360? Can I send MixRadio music to my Xbox 360?

How do I send the music I'm listening on to my Xbox 360?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/779/106

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Nokia Play To" app to stream to almost all devices that supports DLNA. As far as I know, Xbox supports DLNA. but I don't know how to connect it to the phone. But here is link that shows how to connect Xbox through DLNA.

"  http://apcmag.com/how-to-stream-video-to-a-dlna-device.htm  "

Answer (score 1):

Lumia Play To ( Nokia Play to ) is easy to use.
1. open the app and select the media type you want to stream
2. search for the media and open it
3. now the app shows you the network you are connected to and the available and supported devices. It should appear your XBox under "Stream to" , but you have to use the same network for both devices ( windowsphone and XBox ).
It should work even if, for example, you use a router and your wind.phone is connected via Wi-Fi but your XBox via cable. The important thing is to use the same router for both devices.