# How to stream audio from PC to phone?

Tags: audio, streaming

Is it possible to stream my desktop PC's audio to my Lumia 930 via WiFi, like a WiFi Headphone or something?

It seems to me that there is no built-in service or (good) app currently out there!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/779/106

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it's currently not possible to use your phone as a simple playing device using wifi or Bluetooth.

Here are a two things you can try:

Stream files from your PC to your phone:
This can be done for example using one of the DLNA / UPNP players (e.g. [Smart Player](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/smart-player/65ce56eb-28b1-42aa-83e5-2ab808c8510d)) in the store. Or even complete streaming solutions like [Plex](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/plex/4854f786-ea4b-4db0-b67a-4645c04225d4).

Or use one of the great [VLC remote apps](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/search?q=vlc%20remote) which can output the audio on your phone (e.g. [VLC Mobile Remote:Video & Music](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/vlc-mobile-remote-video-music/8ad51406-1c5e-4024-8ffa-f9bc1e21108f)).

I realize this is not as comfortable as it could be so you should consider voting for this feature on the [Windows Phone UserVoice site](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com).

Comment: Perhaps you could add links to some of the apps you mentioned?

Comment: Done. Wrote first answer on my phone.