# streaming video from Windows 10 PC connected over same network

Tags: streaming, sharing

I use use ES File Explorer to steam or browser PC's files on Android device. For that I use samba server on Linux and Mac but I am not sure how to do that on Windows 10

I want to browser Windows 10 files on my Windows 10 Phone and steam videos and stuff. How would I do that?

I have enabled file sharing on Windows PC(from control Panel) but don't know what app would I use on Windows Phone to achieve that. Microsoft's default File Explorer doesn't seem to have that feature

Comment: See also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/779/106

Comment: Have you tried a DLNA client, such as [this one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/acg-media-player/9nblggh698c7). Windows Media Player on your PC can be used as a DLNA server

Answer (score -1):

You can use **[PC Remote](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/pc-remote/9wzdncrfhvwt)** app.You can use your phone as keyboard, mouse, interactive remote desktop, *transfer files* to and fro, integrated remotes for your favorite media players, and lot more.

You can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/pc-remote/9wzdncrfhvwt).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Remote Desktop app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps) on the Windows 10 PC and Windows mobile. It allows you to use all the programs in the PC and ou will have access to all th files in your PC. Yoour phone and PC must be connected to the same Wi-Fi network.